# ASP.NET MVC 5 updating object which includes nested lists, cause duplicates in database

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I am developing a system in which I have a model that includes one-to-one and one-to-many relations. for example my models are as following:

```
Public Class TopClass
    Inherits MyBaseClass

    Public Property prop1 As String
    Public Property prop2 As String
    Public Property prop3 As FirstNestedClass
End Class


Public Class FirstNestedClass
    Inherits MyBaseClass

    Public Property prop1 As String
    Public Property prop2 As String
    Public Property prop3 As List(Of SecondNestedClass)
End Class

Public Class SecondNestedClass
    Inherits MyBaseClass

    Public Property prop1 As String
    Public Property prop2 As String        
End Class
```

Here is my controller for updating the changes:

```
  <HttpPost()>
    <ValidateAntiForgeryToken()>
    Function Edit(ByVal MyTopClass As TopClass) As ActionResult
        If ValidateConformityDocDetail(TopClass) Then
            Dim original As TopClass= GetTopClassById(TopClass.Id)

            UpdateModel(original)
            MyDbContext.Entry(original).State = EntityState.Modified
            MyDbContext.SaveChanges()
            Return RedirectToAction("Edit", MyTopClass .Id)
        End If           
    End Function
```

Now, after SaveChanges(), the result in my db for table SecondNestedClass is as bellow(last column is FK):

```
443 1   AM  NULL    post1       0   NULL  
444 2   AM  NULL    NULL        0   NULL  

443 1   AM  NULL    newpost1    0   7     
444 2   AM  NULL    newval      0   7
```

That means, old values remains, and FK change to NULL. It adds two new records and assign the PK to it.

Where is the problem?

Comment: You need to set the entity state of the children to EntityState.Unchanged, EntityState.Modified or EntityState.Added.

Comment: What about big objects? There are many nested objects, and set all nested and also their nested collections are sometimes impossible.

Comment: You look at [GraphDiff](https://github.com/zzzprojects/GraphDiff)